# How to analyse a random walk with random transition probabilities

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a $1$-dimensional random walk with discrete time steps. We start at the origin and at each integer position there is possibly different probability of moving right one step, or left one step.

For each position $i$ a single coin toss is made to fix the transition probabilities at that position.

With probability $1/2$ there  is a probability of moving right of $2/3$ and probability of moving left of $1/3$.

With probability $1/2$ there is a probability of moving left of $2/3$ and probability of moving right of $1/3$.

For a given position $i$ this coin toss is only ever done once so the transition probabilities for that position are then fixed forever.

If you start at the origin, how far away do you expect to be after $n$ steps?  I would be happy with a large $n$ approximation if that is easier.

Comment: By symmetry the expected position remains $0$, as with the simple case

Comment: @Henry Yes. In case I wasn't clear. I mean the mean absolute distance from the origin.

Comment: It could be interesting that your final position depends on your first move from point $0$ in this manner that if you know the first move, suppose $1$, your expected long-range position is one,\\
And so one ... !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subject is huge and called *random walks in random environment*. The [lecture notes](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~zeitouni/ps/notes3typ.ps) by Ofer Zeitouni at Saint Flour summer school in 2001 are a classical introduction but there are other good texts also available on the web.

A (perhaps counterintuitive) result one soon encounters in this theory concerns the model you describe, where each site $i$ in $\mathbb Z$ is given some probabilities $p_i$ and $q_i=1-p_i$ of transitions to the right $i\to i+1$ and to the left $i\to i-1$ respectively, and the random variables $(p_i)$ are i.i.d.

Then a necessary and sufficient condition for recurrence, almost surely with respect to the environment (see $(\ast)$ below), is not the condition that $E(p_0)=E(q_0)$, that is, $E(p_0)=\frac12$, but that $E(\log p_0)=E(\log q_0)$, that is, $$E\left(\log\frac{p_0}{1-p_0}\right)=0\tag{$\dagger$}.$$
$(\ast)$ Let us be more explicit about this point. 
Call $e=(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z}$ the environment, $\mathbb P$ its distribution, and, for each $e$, $P_e$ the distribution of the random walk conditionally on the environment $e$. Finally, let $\tau$ the first return time to $0$ by the random walk starting from $0$. 
Then the almost sure recurrence referred to above is the fact that $\mathbb P(A)=1$ where $$A=\{e\mid P_e(\tau\lt\infty)=1\},$$ and it holds when $(\dagger)$ holds. Otherwise,  $\mathbb P(A)=0$, that is, $P_e(\tau\lt\infty)\lt1$, $\mathbb P(\mathrm de)$-almost surely.

Comment: This looks interesting but I don't think it addresses my specific question about the expected absolute distance from the origin. Is it just very hard to calculate?

Comment: Of course this addresses the question about the expected distance from the origin. Did you try to check the reference mentioned in the answer? If you did not, where is this conversation going to?

Comment: Yes I did. However they are long and detailed and it is not easy for me to see which part of Chapter 2 directly relates to my question. I don't doubt that if I understood all the material in those notes I could answer my own question however which I think is your suggestion. Also, being in postscript the notes are hard to search.

Comment: The part leading to the transience/recurrence result I cite is not *that* involved. Anyway, to declare that this does not "address (your) specific question" is a peculiar approach to my contribution, to say the least.

Comment: Please don't misinterpret my comments as anything but grateful. I just have no idea at all how to go from a result about transience/recurrence to computing the expected absolute distance from the origin.

Comment: There is no (automatic) way "to go from a result about transience/recurrence to computing the expected absolute distance from the origin". The literature I sent you to explains various asymptotic regimes for the distance from the origin. If I remember correctly, a regime which excited the people when it was first exhibited is one where the scaling is $(\log n)^2$. But, as I said to begin with, "the subject is huge".